# Toggle method in jQuery is not responding to events

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am brand new to jQuery. I am trying to use the toggle method.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("h2").toggle(function() {
        function() {
            $(this).next().addClass("open");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).next().removeClass("open");
        }
    });
});
```

The html and css were provided by the book I am using to learn. I am not going to post the html and css because I do not want to break copyright. However I can say that there is a class called open in the css and that the div that is suppose to flip between having and not having the class of open is the directly next to the h2 heading.

Comment: toggle method has been removed use click event instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$("h2").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("open");
});
```

Comment: This is the intended way of replacing the toggle method in this case.